# Non-destructively iterating over a Rust collection, but not by reference

Tags: iterator, rust, move-semantics

I can write the following two ways, the second is inspired by [What is the idiomatic way to create a collection of references to methods that take self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980343/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-create-a-collection-of-references-to-methods-that-t):

```
channels.iter().flat_map(|c|c.to_uppercase()).collect(),
channels.clone().into_iter().flat_map(char::to_uppercase).collect(),
```

The second line has to clone the collection because `char::to_uppercase` doesn't accept a reference as it's argument and `.iter()` provides references and `.into_iter()` moves the collection.

Is there a way to do this that doesn't need to clone the collection or create a closure? I don't hate closures, I promise, and I know they're just turned into (usually inline) function calls in LLVM anyway, but I like the cleanness of referring to a function like in the second line and would prefer to use it if it can be done without the clone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Iterator` has a [`cloned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) method which is equivalent to `.map(|x| x.clone())` which, in case of `Copy` types is equivalent to `.map(|&x| x)`. This way you can write

```
channels.iter().cloned().flat_map(char::to_uppercase).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function that takes a reference. You can even put it inside another function, if you want to keep it close to its usage.

```
fn foobar() {
    fn to_uppercase(c: &char) -> ::std::char::ToUppercase {
        c.to_uppercase()
    }

    // [...]

    let channels_upper = channels.iter().flat_map(to_uppercase).collect();
}
```